# Поверх других окон, телефон

Tags: python, android, kivy

Как можно реализовать так, чтобы было приложение на телефон, которое добавляло кнопку, отображающуюся поверх других окон (просто подскажите, как сделать кнопку поверх всех окон на телефоне)

Comment: [пример](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846541/what-is-windowmanager-in-android)